# Proving that a multiplication between a convex and concave function is convex

Tags: calculus

here is a problem I am struggling with:

Let f(x) be strictly increasing and strictly convex, and g(x) be strictly increasing and concave, then is also true that h(x)=f(x)g(x) is convex?

Both f(x) and g(x) are twice continuos and twice differentiable functions.

thanks!

Comment: well, take the second derivative and see if it is always positive. $(fg)'' = f''g+2f'g'+fg''$ does not seem to have to be positive unless $f$ and $g$ are also assumed to be positive.

Comment: This is false. Try $-\frac{1}{\sqrt x}$ and $x^2$ for $x>0.$ Indeed, in this case, the reverse is the case. That is, their product is concave on their common domain.

Answer (score 1):

As dezdichado was saying in a comment, you have to look in general at the second derivative.
You have, for each product $fg$, that $(fg)' = f'g + fg'$ and $(fg)'' = f''g + f'g' + f'g' + fg''$.
That means $(fg)'' = f''g + 2f'g' + fg''$. We know $2f'g' > 0$ and $f'' > 0$, $g'' \geq 0 $.
If, as you say in your comment, $f$ and $g$ are also strictly positive, then $f''g > 0$ and $fg'' \geq 0$, so $(fg)'' = f''g + 2f'g' + fg'' > 0$ and we proved $h$ is convex.

Answer (score 0):

$f(x) = x^2$ and $g(x) = -x^{-2}$ over the domain $x\in\mathbb R^+$.

If you insist on $g > 0$, we can restrict the target domain to $x \in (0,1)$ and get $f(x) = x^2 + 3/2 + \epsilon$ and $g(x) = -x^2 + 2x$, which has $h(x)$ become concave down everywhere. without the $\epsilon$, $h(x) = -x^4 +2x^3 - \frac{3}{2}x^2+3x$ is actually straight at $x=1/2$.

Comment: sorry, I have to edit the question. They are strictly increasing and strictly positive with $x \in (0,c)$, and $c<\infy$

Comment: were you going to edit the question?